# Custom Button of type UIButtonTypeInfoLight

Tags: ios, uibutton, selector, mkannotationview

I created a CustomButton why do I need to pass as parameter in a @selector. The custom button is part of a annotationView. In CustomButton I put as property UIButtonType, but in the output  nothing comes out. The output is a button with nothing, and when I get to touch up inside the annotation disappear while I want to open a view controller.

This is the code in CustomButton.h

```
@interface CustomButton : UIButton{

}

@property (nonatomic, strong)NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, assign)UIButtonType  typeButton;
@end
```

in CustomButton.m

```
@implementation CustomButton.h

@synthesize name;
@synthesize buttonType;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

         self.typeButton = UIButtonTypeInfoLight;

    }
return self;
}
```

in MapViewController.m

```
 -(void)loadDetailListViewController: (CustomButton *)aName{ 

             //I want to open a viewController 
             //.......
  }

 - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapview viewForAnnotation:(id 
 <MKAnnotation>)annotation
  {
       //.......  

       MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView*) [mapView 
                dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];


       annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                  reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];

     //.........

     CustomButton *rightButton = [CustomButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     [rightButton setName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.nameTable]];

     [rightButton addTarget:self action: @selector(loadDetailListViewController:) 
                                forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

     annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
     annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
     annotationView.draggable = YES;
     return annotationView;
   }
```

Why when I touch up inside the annotation disappear?

Comment: If all you want to do is access some annotation-related info in the loadDetailListViewController method, you can just use a regular UIButton and use the calloutAccessoryControlTapped delegate method in which you can access view.annotation.

Comment: How do I? You please show me an example?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565197/how-to-find-which-annotation-send-showdetails and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334068/show-another-view-when-map-annotation-are-clicked.

Comment: @AnnaKarenina thanks a lot, now it all works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do follow the documentation instructions:

> buttonWithType: Creates and returns a new button of the specified
>   type.
>
> - (id)buttonWithType:(UIButtonType)buttonType
>
> Parameters
>
> buttonType The button type. See UIButtonType for the possible values.
>
> Return Value
>
> A newly created button.
>
> Discussion This method is a convenience constructor for creating
>   button objects with specific configurations. **It you subclass UIButton,**
>    **this method does not return an instance of your subclass. If you want**
>    **to create an instance of a specific subclass, you must alloc/init the**
>    **button directly.**
>
> When creating a custom button—that is a button with the type
>   UIButtonTypeCustom—the frame of the button is set to (0, 0, 0, 0)
>   initially. Before adding the button to your interface, you should
>   update the frame to a more appropriate value.

Your code works somehow while you are using `UIButtonTypeCustom` at `buttonWithType:`, bad things will happen if someone change it (like to `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect`).

As you are not using `CustomButton -initWithFrame:` anywhere in the code but provided it's implementation, I can suggest you wanted to use it as the desired initializer which is fine.